# Alter view after table rename or drop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following sample data.

--Tables:

```
create table mtest1
(
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
);
create table mtest2
(
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
);
create table mtest3
(
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
);
insert into mtest1 values(1,'mtest1');
insert into mtest2 values(1,'mtest2');
insert into mtest3 values(1,'mtest3');
```

--Views:

```
create view mview1 
as
select * from mtest1

create view mview2 
as
select * from mtest1
union all 
select * from mtest2

create view mview3
as
select * from mtest1
union all 
select * from mtest2
union all
select * from mtest3
```

**Note**: Now I want to create view which contains all other views named as `mviewall`. Between creating view `mviewall` some tables gets dropped 
and I want to handle this exeception while creating view `mviewall`.

For example: I renamed or drop the table `mtest2` which is referred in the views `mview2` and `mview3` and I want to alter those views which got an error of invalid object `mtest2`.

**My try**:

--Procedure : For creating View `mviewall`

```
alter procedure spmtest_createView
as
begin

    declare @ErrorTable varchar(max)=''
    declare @ErrorView varchar(max) = ''
    declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

begin try

    if exists(select 1 from sys.views where name='mviewall' and type='v')
    drop view mviewall;

    set @sql = '
    create view mviewall 
    as 
    select * from mview1 
    union all 
    select * from mview2 
    union all 
    select * from mview3';
    print(@sql);
    exec(@sql);

end try
begin catch
    SELECT @ErrorTable = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorView = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
    SELECT @ErrorTable = REPLACE(@ErrorTable,'''','');
    SELECT @ErrorTable = SUBSTRING(@ErrorTable,CHARINDEX('dbo.',@ErrorTable),LEN(@ErrorTable)-CHARINDEX('dbo.',@ErrorTable))
    SELECT @ErrorTable = REPLACE(@ErrorTable,'dbo.','');
    print(@ErrorTable);
    print(@ErrorView);
    exec spalterview @ErrorTable,@ErrorView;

end catch   

end
```

--Procedure : For alter view

```
alter procedure spalterview 
@ErrorTable varchar(255),
@ErrorView varchar(255)
as

begin

    DECLARE @Tables VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @DSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SELECT @Tables = STUFF((SELECT ' SELECT * FROM [dbo].['+vt.TABLE_NAME+'] UNION ALL ' 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE vt
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tbl ON vt.TABLE_NAME = tbl.TABLE_NAME AND vt.TABLE_CATALOG = tbl.TABLE_CATALOG
    WHERE VIEW_NAME = @ErrorView AND vt.TABLE_NAME <> @ErrorTable
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,' ')

    SET @Tables = LEFT(@Tables,LEN(@Tables)-10);

    SET @DSQL = 'ALTER VIEW ['+@ErrorView+'] AS 
                '+@Tables+';';

    print(@DSQL);
    EXEC(@DSQL);

    exec spmtest_createView; --Calling this because of multiple exception may occur  

end
```

--Rename table:

```
exec sp_rename 'mtest2', 'mtest22';
```

--Execute SP:

```
exec spmtest_createView;
```

--Get view data:

```
select * from mviewall;
```

But unable to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong in general because you think that the only thing that can change in your environment is existance of any table.

The real world is more complicated, someone can change any table by altering `column type`, adding/dropping any `columns`, and in all these cases your `create view` statement will fail because of incompatibility of types in union all or mismatching columns number in every member of union all.

Becides, it'a also always bad to use `*` in your `view` definition, simple recreation(drop + add) of any `column` will break your view.

So you should just change your approach, there is no way to secure create views in dynamic code as too much things can change.

Maybe it's usefull to you to use `with schemabinding` option when creating your views, it will stop any attempt of change the underlying tables structure.

---

Now to your errors.
Your first `proc` finishes in `catch block` with `@ErrorTable = 'Invalid object name mtest1'` and `@ErrorView = 'mview1'`passed into the second proc.

The second proc executes a code similar to this one:

```
SELECT --@Tables = 
--stuff((SELECT ' SELECT * FROM [dbo].['+vt.TABLE_NAME+'] UNION ALL ' 
vt.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE vt
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tbl ON vt.TABLE_NAME = tbl.TABLE_NAME AND vt.TABLE_CATALOG = tbl.TABLE_CATALOG
WHERE VIEW_NAME = 'mview1' AND vt.TABLE_NAME <>'Invalid object name mtest1'
--FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,' ')
```

I commented some parts of original code to show you that it returns

```
null
```

This is because as soon as you invalidated your view `'mview1'` by dropping one base table is disappeared from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, so your `inner join` returns `null`.

The next piece of code sets `@DSQL` to `null` and executes `null`.

Finally, the last row calls the `first proc` that finishes in `cath block` that calls the `second proc` that executes `null` and calls the `first proc`....

Fortunately this `loop` is interrupted by server as soon as nested level limit is reached.